# CloudFormation - Route Table route Propagation for Tansit Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating the following resources using CloudFormation:

- VPC
- Two Public Subnet
- Two private Subnet
- Route Tables for the Subnet's

I have created a site-to-site VPN with my on-prem office manually.
I have created the transit gateway manually and attached my VPN to it.
Now since I will be creating the VPC with CloudFormation, I thought to avoid manual work lets associate VPC to Transit Gateway and propagate the route in the Route Tables in the CloudFormation Script itself. 
Please refer the following snippet for the same:

```
  VPCTransitGateayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayAttachment
    Properties: 
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      TransitGatewayId: 'tgw-1234567890'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

#TransitGateWay Routes
  TransitGateWayPublicRouteTableRoutes:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/16'
      TransitGatewayId: 'tgw-1234567890'

  TransitGateWayPrivateRouteTable1Routes:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/16'
      TransitGatewayId: 'tgw-1234567890'  

  TransitGateWayPrivateRouteTable2Routes:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/16'
      TransitGatewayId: 'tgw-1234567890'
```

But I am facing the following error when I execute the script.

```
The transitGateway ID 'tgw-1234567890' does not exist. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidTransitGatewayID.NotFound; Request ID: 30d31120-f9e2-4870-a378-55bc9a36f5bb)
```

For the **AWS::EC2::Route** resource.
I am not able to understand what is the issue. The [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-route.html#cfn-ec2-route-routetableid) states the option for Transit Gateway for AWS::EC2::Route.
What else I am missing here ?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue in cloudformation, the problem was the routes must wait for the `AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayAttachment`, I ran the cloudformation template with all of my routes that needed the TransitGatewayId paramter commented, then uncommented the routes, and it worked.

There is [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) that this is required for internet gateways attachments, but my test shows, this is also required for TransitGatewayAttachments.

What we should do is add a DependsOn and that should solve the problem.

Comment: Oh..Thanks for the information , let me check and implement this. I will get back to you asap.